# Can't get date.toLocaleString() to change time to locale

Tags: javascript, date, datetime-format

I'm trying to output dates in JavaScript. The page is going to be used by folk in multiple timezones and languages to I figured it would be best to use `toLocaleString()`.

I've tried the example from MSDN but it isn't working:

```
var date = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 11, 20, 3, 0, 0));

document.write(date.toLocaleString('en-US', { hour12: false }));
// → "12/19/2012, 19:00:00"
```

but instead I get

```
12/20/2012, 03:00:00
```

I've tried a few browsers both in Linux and Windows but I'm just getting the same result. Is there something obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: Why do expect 19 o'clock?

Comment: The documentation suggests that toLocaleString also adjusts the date to the locale timezone. See the section *Example: Using locales*: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

Comment: But there is no such thing as a locale timezone, e.g. 'en-US' could mean UTC-5 down to UTC-10.

Comment: It could - but there's documented examples of the method using a locale seem to make a "best guess". Either way, what I use isn't matching what's on MSDN and if the documentation is incorrect (or more likely incomplete) then that's fine - at least I know I'm not strictly doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fourth argument to `Date.UTC` is hours (0 to 23) so in your case it's 03:00:00 if you are located in the "zero" timezone. The MSDN example was probably written by someone sitting in e.g. Seattle.

Answer (score 2):

The `toLocaleString` method is about formatting, it formats the date to an *American English* format, it does not care about timezones, nor could it.

If you want to deal with time zones, I definitely recommend using a library, like **MomentJS**, unfortunately working with time is a pain in JavaScript (and to be fair, in most languages). However, if you want to fiddle with native JS, then take a look at the [`getTimezoneOffset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) method.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking at `getTimezoneOffset` right now so +1. Will come back with results.

Comment: But why do you need the offset?

Comment: I'm pulling a UTC time from the server and I want it to display the user's local time.